# text overflow not working on links in responsive menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have this mega-menu, some of the links have fairly long names, when the window is made smaller the longer links overlap text on the the other columns. I added the following rules to the `ul` class,

```
.sub-menu-lists {
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I had tried adding these rules to the `li` class `.hover_drop_down` and also `.hover_drop_down a`, neither of these helped.

The overlap is gone, but the link is just cut off. I can not get the ellipsis to show up. I want them to trail to the end of the column.

here is my codepen, going into the software menu shows the problem. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this??

https://codepen.io/iamgonge/full/egqPQR

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign these settings to the `li` elements, not to the `ul` as you did. So, that's this selector:

```
ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li {...}
```